# Can we prove that in a convex space, Weakly closed=> weak* closed ??

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-topology

We know that weak* Topology is smaller than weak topology. So weak* closed sets are weakly closed.
Banach Mazur theorem says "Strongly closed implies weakly closed if space is convex." can we expect this result in weak and weak * topology as well??

Comment: What do you mean by a convex space? I can't think of a meaning of the term that wouldn't cover an infinite-dimensional Hilbert Space, and in that case, the weak and strong topologies do not coincide.

Comment: I think the OP means convex set when he says convex space.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that $c_0^{*}=l^{1}$ and $(l^{1})^{*}=l^{\infty}$. The set $C=\{(a_n)\in l^{1}: \sum_n a_n=1\}$ is convex, weakly closed but not $weak^{*}$ closed: the basis vectors $e_n$ are in this set, they converge to $0$ in $weak^{*}$ sense.

Comment: $c_0$ is the space of all sequences that converge to $0$ with the sup norm.

Comment: Interesting, the sequence $e_n$ does not converge weakly in $\ell^1$. Even more; it is a bounded sequence in $\ell^1$ that has no weakly convergent subsequences. These are all weird consequences of the fact that $\ell^1$ is not reflexive. Thank you for this answer, it's been thought-provoking for me.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I am not a Functional Analyst but since weak and weak* coincide in reflexive spaces I was naturally led to this non-reflexive space.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X=l^\infty$, $C=c_0$. Then $X = (l_1)^*$. The point $x=(1,1,\dots)$ is in $l^\infty\setminus c_0$. However the sequence 
$$
x_n = (\underbrace{1,1,\dots,1}_{first\ n\ entries},0,0,\dots)
$$
of elements in $c_0$
converges weak-star to $x$. Hence the closed subspace $c_0$ is not (sequentially) weak-star closed.